# Euro-Bund Futures fair value

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates, futures, bond-futures

I am trying to calculate the fair value via discounting the cashflows of the (synthetic underlying) for the euro bund futures (https://www.eurex.com/ex-en/markets/int/fix/government-bonds/Euro-Bund-Futures-137298).

To save you some reading the underlying is a theoretical 10Y 6% per annum bond.

It seems trivial to calculate this price but for a weird reason that I can not find I can not end up with what would seem a reasonable result.
For example see the price at expiration for this September 2020 euro bund future https://www.barchart.com/futures/quotes/GGU20 . The price at expiration (09/08/20) is 176.93, I assume that if I use the prevailing yields (zero-rates for the German government) at the time of expiration and find the present value of the theoretical bond I should end up with a price pretty close to 176.93 but I end up with roughly 166.

PS. Do not mind conversion factors cheapest to delivery etc they should not matter in what i am trying to achieve. Either I'm doing a mathematical mistake (I doubt it) or there is a logical flaw in my idea.

PS2. These are the prevailing yields at the time of expiration
[image: yields]

Comment: Can you explain why CTD / conversion factor are not relevant here? Shouldn't the futures, close to expiry, more or less follow the (converted) CTD, i.e. it will not follow a fictitious 6%- bond, but the (converted-at-6%-CF) CTD, no?

Comment: I thought a lot about it, the problem should be conceptual. I.e. what is the underlying of this bond future? is it the fictitious 6% 10Y bond or is it the CTD divided by the conversion factor (CF) ? Assuming the latter then everything is fine, BUT since the conversion factor tries to equalize the CTD with the fictitious bond should both approaches yield similar at least results? i.e. finding the fair value of the fictitious at expiry and finding the fair value of the CTD/CF at expiry shouldn't yield the same result?